# how to align all div inside a div next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to align all divs inside in a div next to each other and no other div of HTML has any effect on it

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
    </div><div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
    </div><div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
    </div>
    </div>
```

my problem is that I can no assign id/class to inside div and if I try

```
div{
   float:left;
}
```

it affect every div of that HTML I want to only align item next to each other wrapper id's divs
and idea and suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I could not understand your goal exactly. Why you don't use ```#wrapper div``` as a selector?

Comment: [massive dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=align+all+divs+inside+a+divs+next+to+each+other+flex+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the wrapper a flexbox using `display: flex`

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" width='50px'>
  </div>
</div>
```